# Empty out a div with jQuery then put it back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have a div with videos set up so that when I click the play button (`.video-play-container`), the video fades in, and then when I click the close button (`.close-video`), the video fades out. The problem was that when the video faded out, it kept playing in the background. Therefore, I emptied out the `src` with this line (`'$(.youtube-player').attr('src', '');`). However, this would be good if the user didn't need to see the video again. But if he wants to open the video back up, the `src` is now empty so he can't see the video. How can I restore the `src` after I have already taken it out so the user can see the video more than once?

```
$('.video-play-container').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-play-container').fadeOut(500);
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(500).show();
    $('#feat-video').fadeIn(500).show();
});

$('.close-video').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#feat-video').fadeOut(500);
    $('.youtube-player').attr('src', '');
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
    $('.video-play-container').show().fadeIn(500);
});
```

Edit: Updated code

```
var src;
src = $('.youtube-player').attr('src');

$('.video-play-container').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-play-container').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(2000).show();
    $('#feat-video').fadeIn(2000).show();
});

$('.close-video').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#feat-video').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.youtube-player').attr('src', '');
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.video-play-container').show().fadeIn(2000);
    $('.youtube-player').attr('src', src);
});
```

Edit: Updated code 2

```
var src;
src = $('.youtube-player').attr('src');

$('.video-play-container').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-play-container').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(2000).show();
    $('#feat-video').fadeIn(2000).show();
});

$('.close-video').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#feat-video').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.video-play-container').show().fadeIn(2000);
    $('.youtube-player').attr('src', '');
    $('.youtube-player').attr('src', src);
});
```

Edit: Updated code 3

```
var src;
src = $('.youtube-player').attr('src');

$('.video-play-container').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-play-container').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(2000).show();
    $('#feat-video').fadeIn(2000).show();
});

$('.close-video').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#feat-video').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $('.youtube-player').attr('src', '');
    });
    $('.video-play-container').show().fadeIn(2000);
    $('.youtube-player').attr('src', src);
});
```

Edit: Updated code 4 (Final)

```
var src;
src = $('.youtube-player').attr('src');

$('.video-play-container').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-play-container').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(2000).show();
    $('#feat-video').fadeIn(2000).show();
});

$('.close-video').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#feat-video').fadeOut(2000);
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $('.youtube-player').attr('src', '');
        $('.youtube-player').attr('src', src);
    });
    $('.video-play-container').show().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: It's hidden, but exists, so is still playing for various reasons.  Take a look at the [YouTube JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

Comment: @Jeremy Yeah, that's what I figured. I've been looking at the YT JS API for the past few hours in fact but I can't seem to grasp the concept. So, I figured this would be an easier fix (if it's even possible).

Comment: Stop the video from playing or, put the `.html()` into a var, then use `remove()`.  Append again later.  Much easier to stop playing using `player.stopVideo():Void`

Comment: @Jeremy I would use the API but my player is in an iframe and it looks like I have to append `?enablejsapi=1` to the end of the src. Unfortunately, I'm not able to change that directly since it's a plugin and it would get wiped out in the next update. Is there a way to append `?enablejsapi=1` to the end of an iframe src with jQuery by any chance?

Comment: That would likely cause a double-access of the page (not a biggie, but more work).  That aside, if it ends up loading in an iframe, then you can't control what's inside anyway so it'd be fruitless.  If a plugin just loads an iframe into the HTML, I'd just replace the plugin with my own code... not that hard to insert my own iframe, right?

Comment: @Jeremy I would if I could, but this plugin doesn't just load a plain player, but a gallery.

Comment: Fair enough.  Sometimes we're stuck with what we have b/c time is never on our side.  Looks like you've got an answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a definition of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but if you insist... To save and restore an attribute,

```
var src;
src = $('.youtube-player').attr('src');
$('.youtube-player').attr('src', '');
// do something else
$('.youtube-player').attr('src', src);
```

To save and restore contents of a tag,

```
var html;
html = $('.youtube-player').html();
$('.youtube-player').empty();
// do something else
$('.youtube-player').html(html)
```

EDIT:

> - Why don't you kill the player at the end of the fade-out?
> - I did that (you can see in the updated code above) but it still looks like it has that flicker

You did *not* do that. `hide(2000)` is *asynchronous*. It will put the fade in the queue, then it will immediately clear out `src` and put it back immediately. Thus, the flicker, as the video disappears and then starts loading back in, all before the fade completes. You want to use the end-of-animation callback on `hide`:

```
$('.overlay').fadeOut(2000, function() {
  $('.youtube-player').attr('src', '');
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I see the logic behind the first block of code and just using that achieves what I need, but what is the second block for? What tag? Do I need to include that too?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your HTML. Your question body asks for the first approach ("how can I restore `src`?") while your question title asks for the second ("empty out a div then put it back?"); so just in case I provided an answer for both. However, neither of the questions is actually the right one, the one Jeremy Miller answered ("how do I stop my video playing when I hide it?" or "how do I load and unload a youtube video dynamically?") :)

Comment: Be careful though: The above code will not work, if you have multiple `.youtube-player`.

Comment: Sorry, can't see, fadeout is too fast to notice. What becomes choppy?

Comment: @Amadan I made the fades a little slower so you can get a better idea. Basically, when I click the close button, I see a quick flicker (I'm guessing this is the src being emptied out) and then it fades out. I included your code into the original code which you can see in the post above.

Comment: Why don't you kill the player at the *end* of the fade-out?

Comment: Answer to this is a bit complex for comments, so I edited the answer to include it.

Comment: Can you check my updated code above to see what I did wrong? It's still flickering.

Comment: You are still replacing `src` immediately (although not with empty one any more): `$('.youtube-player').attr('src', src);` Don't touch `src` until the animation is off-screen (ie. don't touch it outside the `hide` callback).

Comment: @Amadan Gotcha. I put both inside the callback and it seems to be working now. Thank you so much for your help. I learned a little today.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:

Store the src in the data attribute of the youtube-player using Jquery.

As such your code would be:

```
$('.video-play-container').click(function( e ){
    //Check if src is present, else fetches it in the data attribute of the element
    $('.youtube-player').attr('src') || $('.youtube-player).attr('src',$(this).data('src'))
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-play-container').fadeOut(500);
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(500).show();
    $('#feat-video').fadeIn(500).show();
});

$('.close-video').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#feat-video').fadeOut(500);
    //Stores the src in the data attribute before wiping the src clean.
    $('.youtube-player').data('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    $('.youtube-player').attr('src', '');
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
    $('.video-play-container').show().fadeIn(500);
});
```

Another recommendation would be to use a ID, instead of class, if you have a single youtube player. Having several on the same page would make the above code buggy.